# Why does my background slideshow animation have a delay between changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have this bit of code:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
    var bgimages = new Array()
    bgimages[0] = "images/door.jpg"
    bgimages[1] = "images/stephane.jpg"
    bgimages[2] = "images/haotel.jpg"

    //preload images
    var pathToImg = new Array()
    for (i = 0; i < bgimages.length; i++) {
        pathToImg[i] = new Image()
        pathToImg[i].src = bgimages[i]
    }

    var inc = -1

    function bgSlide() {
        if (inc < bgimages.length - 1) inc++
        else inc = 0
        document.body.background = pathToImg[inc].src
    }

    if (document.all || document.getElementById) window.onload = new Function('setInterval("bgSlide()",8000)')
</script>
```

with this CSS:

```
body {
    /*Remove below line to make bgimage NOT fixed*/
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*Use center center in place of 300 200 to center bg image*/
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

It works; it displays a full-sized image as the page background and changes them, but upon the initial refresh of the page, it is a white screen for the first 8 seconds of the script. How do I go about changing it so that it will display something right away?

Comment: Tip: Some semi colons and indentation would make your code even better.

Answer (score 3):

You should either load a background image as a default (like in the CSS) or you should fire off your `document.body.background=pathToImg[inc].src` right after the page loads, before your setInterval (setInterval is going to wait that 8 seconds before it does anything).

Answer (score 0):

Fire bgSlide right away. Then create an Interval that fires it every 8
seconds.

```
   window.onload = function(){
        bgSlide();
        setInterval(function(){
            bgSlide();
        }, 8000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads you are triggering the setInterval for 8 seconds, which means only after 8 seconds will you have your first background image. Try setting a background you want as default via CSS. Other than that you can code a `document.body.background=pathToImg[0]` to trigger before you start the setInterval. Of course in this way you might want to start the rotation at pathToImg[1], otherwise you will have 16 seconds of pathToImg[0].